# Divisibility of numbers in pascal

Tags: pascal

I want to write a pascal program that checks if particular number is divisible by 2, 3, 5, 7, 9 and 11 and whether the sum of the digits is even or odd. In the very end I want to write a statement like "This number is divisible by 5 and 9" and the sum of the numbers is even/odd. What should I do?

Comment: No, I honestly don't even know how to begin.

Comment: A number is even divisible with another number if the remainder is zero. Use the mod operator to check that. Use the Odd function to test whether a number is odd. To make a sum of the digits that makes a number, add the modulus 10 of the number to a sum and divide the number by 10 in a loop until the number is zero.

Comment: You can use **mod** to check the particular number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This's my code, I separate into 2 sections :

```
program checkNumber;
var number : integer;
    divider : string;
    digit1, digit2, sum : integer;

begin

//First//
write('Number : '); readln(number);
if (number MOD 2 = 0) then divider := divider+'2, ';
if (number MOD 3 = 0) then divider := divider+'3, ';
if (number MOD 5 = 0) then divider := divider+'5, ';
if (number MOD 7 = 0) then divider := divider+'7, ';
if (number MOD 9 = 0) then divider := divider+'9, ';
if (number MOD 11 = 0) then divider := divider+'11, ';
write('This number is divisible by '); write(divider);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Second//
digit1 := number DIV 10;
digit2 := number MOD 10;
sum := digit1 + digit2;
write('and the sum of the numbers is ');
if (sum MOD 2 = 0) then write('even') else write('odd');
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

end.
```

> ## First part

You need **MOD**(modulus) operation to get the list of divider values:

```
write('Number : '); readln(number);
if (number MOD 2 = 0) then divider := divider+'2, ';
if (number MOD 3 = 0) then divider := divider+'3, '; //divider 2 3 5 7 9 11
.
.
```

Then save the divider into variable **divider** as string, and write it on monitor.

```
write('This number is divisible by '); write(divider);
```

> ## Second part

You need to separate the digits into single variable using **DIV**(divide) and **MOD**(modulus) operation. In my code, I limit the number input for **2 digit** (1 until 99):

```
digit1 := number DIV 10;
digit2 := number MOD 10;
sum := digit1 + digit2;
```

(You change the code use **if..then..** function if you want input bigger number).

---

Then use **MOD** to check the number is even or odd:

```
if (sum MOD 2 = 0) then write('even') else write('odd');
```

Comment: Yes, it did! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use modulus:

```
program ModulusTest;
begin
        if 8 mod 2 = 0 then
        begin
                write(8);
                writeln(' is even');
        end;
        if 30 mod 5 = 0 then
        begin
                write(30);
                writeln(' is divisible by 5');
        end;
        if 32 mod 5 <> 0 then
        begin
                write(32);
                writeln(' is not divisible by 5');
        end;
end.
```

Modulus is what remains after an integer division :)

Comment: Great, thanks! One question: what does 8, 30, 32 means? Or are they just random numbers and this is just an example?

Comment: There are just totally made up numbers :)

Comment: Okay. And could you tell me why you used <> instead of = in the last example?

Comment: If a number mod a number equals zero, then it means that the first number is divisible by the second number.

Comment: <> simply means not equal - so if the remainder after dividing it by 5 is not zero, it is not divisible by 5.

Comment: Ok, I see. And what about checking whether the sum of the numbers (for example 15) is odd or even? That's the other part of the program. In the very end I want to write a statement like "This number is divisible by 5 and 9" and the sum of the numbers is even/odd.